# How to create a dashboard that takes data from multiple projects in reportportal

Tags: reportportal

is there a way to create a dashboard that shows the stats of different projects in reportportal.
I can create a dashboard for different launches of the same project.

Answer (score 1):

There is no capabilities for that at the moment.
ReportPortal team plans to introduce Organization level, which will be a container for project, thus can grab data from multiple project. But it's in a roadmap for 2020.

For now, there is a way, when you can report all teams/components/projects in one space and slice them by dedicated TAG for each launch.
Then create a filter-tab with specific tag, so teams can see launches related to them. And then dashboards can read data from all the launches.